# Find string between two substrings AND between string and the end of file

Tags: python, regex

I have the following problem. I want to take specific strings from a multiple text file, there is a certain pattern in the text files. for example

```
example_file = "this is a test Pear this should be included1 Apple this should not be included Pear this should be included2 Apple again this should not be included Pear this should be included3"
```

Each file is very different, but in all the file I want the text 1: between the words 'Pear' and 'Apple' i have solved this with the following code:

```
x = re.findall(r'Pear+\s(.*?)Apple', example_file ,re.DOTALL)
```

which returns:

```
['this should be included1 ', 'this should be included2 ']
```

The think which i can not find is that i also want the string on the end, the 'this should be included3' part. So i was wondering if there is a way to specify with regex something like

```
 x = re.findall(r'Pear+\s(.*?)Apple OR EOF', example_file ,re.DOTALL)
```

so how can a match something between the word 'Pear' and EOF (end of file) ? Notice that these are all text files (so not specificly one sentence)

Comment: You probably want to match `Pear\s+` rather than `Pear+\s`. That way you match 1 or more whitespace characters as opposed to 1 or more `'r'` characters ;-)

Comment: If you have a very large input, use [`r'Pear\s+([^A]*(?:A(?!pple)[^A]*)*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/V4f8en/1)

Comment: When given `Pear and Pear and one Apple` what should be returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select either `Apple` or `$` (an anchor matching the end of the string):

```
x = re.findall(r'Pear\s+(.*?)(?:Apple|$)', example_file, re.DOTALL)
```

`|` specifies two alternatives, and `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, so that the parser knows to pick either `Apple` or `$` as the match.

Note that I replaced `Pear+\s` with `Pear\s+`, as I suspect you want to match arbitrary whitespace, not an arbitrary number of `r` characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> example_file = "this is a test Pear this should be included1 Apple this should not be included Pear this should be included2 Apple again this should not be included Pear this should be included3"
>>> re.findall(r'Pear\s+(.*?)(?:Apple|$)', example_file, re.DOTALL)
['this should be included1 ', 'this should be included2 ', 'this should be included3']
```

Comment: I think the `Pear+\s` should be written as `Pear\s+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: probably; it'll work for the demo input, but they probably meant to match one or more spaces, not one or more `r` characters ;-)

Comment: You maybe have missed a colon (`:`) after the question mark in your non-capturing group explanation.

Comment: @Niitaku: ta, I did.